# knockoutjs foreach binding get the length value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
<div data-bind="foreach: people">
   <div data-bind="if: personId().length > 1">more than 1 person</div>
</div>
```

The perosnId is not observable array values. The value like 123, 222, 133, 444 123. So it does not get the length value. So how do I get the length value not update the JavaScript. I want to get pesonId().length that is 2 values('123')

Thanks,

Comment: Please dont forget to mark as correct if it was useful. X)

Answer (score 0):

If this values was numeric try this to parse to string `(personId()+"").length`, so now you can get the length of the string, for example "123" has the length 3.

So your code will be like that:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: people">
   <div data-bind="if: (personId()+'').length > 1">more than 1 person</div>
</div>
```

> Note that I concat the numeric value to an string, I do this to parse to string, because is the faster way, see the performance test here: [numeric to string test](http://jsperf.com/number-to-string/2)